# Removing a DOM element using JQLite empty() command doesn't unregister the listeners/observers registered in the DOM element's associated controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a "MainController" which defines a directive "tilesContainer" that adds and removes tiles on the main page when data is updated. Each Tile has its own controller "ChildTileController" that observes/listens to the broadcasted messages from parent controller "MainController". In the directive, every time the data is updated/reloaded, the existing tiles are removed and new tiles are added in the DOM. All the tiles are removed using the JQLite code "element.empty()". As per the docs the scope and events are destroyed when you remove the children from DOM. But the observer for "$destroy" is not called in the "ChildTileController". Also, for every data reload/update the listeners are doubled on the previous count. Please refer the plunk "http://plnkr.co/edit/jo20gFcBGLz0kTJXywX2?p=preview". click on reload and then broadcast buttons and observe the console to see the multiplied listeners. I wanted a solution to destroy the listeners and scope if required. Below is the code in the directive to add and remove the tiles/children.

```
var addTiles = function(){
                angular.forEach(data, function (title, index) {
                  var tile = $compile('<div ng-controller="ChildTileController" style="width:50px; height: 50px; background-color: green; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" ng-click="tileClicked('+title+');"><h3>'+title+'</h3></div>')(scope);
                  element.append(tile);
                });
              }
              var removeAllTiles = function(){  
                 /* 
            var children = element.children();
            console.log(children.length);
            angular.element(children[0]).on('$destroy', function() {
              console.log("Child element 1 Destroyed"+angular.element(children[0]).scope().listener());
              angular.element(children[0]).scope().listener();
            });
            angular.element(children[1]).on('$destroy', function() {
              console.log("Child element 2 Destroyed");
              angular.element(children[1]).scope().listener();
            });
            angular.element(children[2]).on('$destroy', function() {
              console.log("Child element 3 Destroyed");
              angular.element(children[2]).scope().listener();
            });
            */
                element.empty();
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials it is found that, removing/emptying a DOM element using JQLite remove() and empty() commands does not destroy the scope. You need to explicitly destroy the scope of element (or child element) on which ng-controller is defined using $destroy() command. Please refer the below code:

```
var removeAllTiles = function(){ 
                var children = element.children();
                angular.forEach(children, function (child, index) {
                    angular.element(child).scope().$destroy();
                });                    
                element.empty();
              }
```

Ref the updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/jo20gFcBGLz0kTJXywX2?p=preview